# How to count members of a set in a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a list of letters and letter clusters, like this:

```
['x', 'str', 'a', 'pr']
```

I have a string that I need to know how many total occurrences of any member of the list are in it:

stripe = 1, rope = 0,, rprpraxp = 4, etc

Now I can loop over the members of the list counting occurrences of each member and then total them, like this:

```
sublist = ['x', 'str', 'a', 'pr']
string = "rprpraxp"
inst = 0
for member in sublist:
    inst = inst + string.count(member)
print(inst)
```

However I am wondering if I am missing a shorter, simpler, more intuitive and more Pythonic way of counting the members of a set of items in another string, something like:

```
inst = string.multicount(['x', 'str', 'a', 'pr'])
```

Anything like this exist?

Thanks.

Comment: Use the package `collections` -- see the `counter` object.

Comment: What if strings overlap? Example: list is ['ab', 'ba'] and string is 'aba'. Is the answer 1 or 2?

Comment: I'm coding my text to make sure that does not happen - but good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
sublist = ['x', 'str', 'a', 'pr']
string = "rprpraxp"
print(sum(map(string.count, sublist)))
```

Comment: Because sets are faster?

Comment: Yes, sets have faster lookups than list. You won't notice any difference in this case because it is a small list of strings. I'm just pointing it out. I edited to let it as a list though it is completely trivial in this case.

Comment: Just to confirm, what you are calling a set is the same thing as a tuple, right? Or is this a new type I haven't bumped into yet?

Comment: Yea Initially I used `tuples` and it was my mistake. I understand the confusion. here is the way your create both `mytuple = (1,2,3)` and `myset = {1,2,3}`. Set can also be initialize like this `myset=set(1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> S = "rprpraxp"
>>> L = ['x', 'str', 'a', 'pr']
>>> sum(S.count(e) for e in L if e in S)
4
```

Comment: Won't you get the same answer if you omit `if e in S`?

Comment: @Robᵩ: Sure. Might even be a bit faster.